# Electric Motor-drive type/setup recommendations needed. I need 90,000 rpm at the output shaft @ a power of 30kW.?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, induction-motor

I am repurposing a car turbocharger to be driven by electric motor. It requires around 30kW, @90,000 rpm to function in the desired range. Which type of motor should I use? I'd probably have to use a gearbox/belts, but is there any way to avoid them, I would much prefer a direct drive system. I need control over RPM as well.

Comment: Sounds a lot more like a supercharger than a turbocharger. I guess I'd look at what power source can supply 30kW and what motors are available. Probably a hybrid EV motor and controller driving a geared-up blower.

Comment: AC induction or DC / BLDC. Which motor would be preferable here? Assuming a gearbox in between.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, I love to hear from people who are passionate about electronics and want to build their own stuff, and I think it sounds like a neat project that you are embarking on, that said I have to state a few things about how SE works and a few other things that people in here will find obvious;

Number one: What work/research of your own have you done already?.. SE is not a site where people do other peoples work for them.

Number two: If you need to ask a question as simple/basic as that on SE then you probably don't have the knowledge necessary to work with 30kW electric..

Comment: .. motors running at 90.000 rpm. not to mention that to get it working well and in a safe way you will need many times more knowledge/information than anyone here will be willing/able to provide you, in other words; there is a reason people do a multiple-years university degree in electrical engineering..

So ask yourself; what exactly are you expecting to gain from asking this question here?

..And I am really not trying to be rude.

Comment: A turbine engine would work. perfectly balanced

Answer (score 1):

The turbo's compressor impeller can spin that fast because it is fairly small in diameter and made from lightweight, high-strength materials.

Motors, by their nature, need magnetics, so that restricts the armature material choices somewhat. As a result, a motor suitable for that kind of RPM would have to have a long, skinny armature to withstand the forces at high RPM. And if you look at the KERS motor-generators used for turbos on F1 cars, that's exactly what they look like.

Here's an example of a 'hybrid' turbo from Magnetti Marelli:
[image]

Link: http://speed.academy/future-boost-hybrid-turbochargers-and-thermal-energy-recovery-systems/2/

Being a hybrid system, this is a bit different than what you're asking. Nevertheless the design challenge is the same: developing a motor armature that can spin at turbo speeds with enough armature coil flux capacity to handle 30KW and not fry itself in the process.

There's another possibility: use a gearbox to step up the turbo speed from the motor. This relaxes some constraints on the armature, at the expense of some losses in the gears.

That said, *real* (not hokey bolt-on) electric superchargers are coming to production cars. More here: https://www.garrettmotion.com/electric-hybrid/garrett-e-turbo/

These will tend to show up on hybrid cars. Why? Hybrids have high-voltage high-current power available - a big advantage for high-powered motors, like the 40HP motor you propose.

Comment: I'd speculate that an "outrunner" containing the magnetics via the hoop strength of a steel rotor could go pretty fast, but I still don't know about 90k rpm at the size/power required.

Comment: Which motor would you recommend for the system? AC induction or DC / BLDC? I've just designed a 4-stage gearbox for a rpm mutiplication of ~58/ That ought to give me around 90krpm @1500 motor rpm (typical for an induction AC). Or is there a better option?

Comment: Take a look at the kinds of motors used in hybrid vehicles.